# Is tid key reserved with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, key

When I log the json string of a key named tid, it always returns 0. Check the following example.

```
var transaction = {tid:1, type:0, time:126312736};
var transStr = JSON.stringify(transaction);
console.log(transStr);
```

The beginning part of that log looks like:

```
{"tid":0,"
```

When I change the key to something else like tidd, I get the expected value of 1. My question is why does that happen? Is tid reserved maybe?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, problem may be somewhere else. Can you post a demo?

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into my console and it worked just fine, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See for yourself:

```js
var transaction = {tid:1, type:0, time:126312736};
var transStr = JSON.stringify(transaction);
alert(transStr);
```

Comment: Ah I had two json keys with the same value.